# I am curious about how to access the clipboard using accessibility services in Android 10

Tags: android

As of Android 10, accessing the clipboard in the background is blocked

However, there are apps that access the clipboard in the background using AccessibilityService.

I would like to know how to access the clipboard in the background using AccessibilityService

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

**Privacy changes in Android 10**

Limited access to clipboard data
Unless your app is the default input method editor (IME) or is the app that currently has focus, your app cannot access clipboard data on Android 10 or higher.

Still you can try to grants READ_LOGS permission